# Unable to import files under shared directory

Tags: typescript, express

I have a question about specifying the path for Express (Typescript).

### Directory structure

```
├── backend
│   └── app
│   　   ├── node_modules
│   　   ├── src
│   　   │   └── ...
│   　   ├── tsconfig.json
│   　   └── package.json
├── common
│   └── types
│   　   └── index.ts
├── frontend
 ...
```

### backend tsconfig.json contents

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016", 
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@common/*": [
        "../../common/*"
      ]
    }, 
    "esModuleInterop": true,  
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,  
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  }
}
```

- backend created with express and typescript
- common places files shared between backend and frontend

### Contents of question

In the above directory structure, I would like to import files under common from backend, but currently the following error is output and it fails.

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:7:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@common/types/index' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 import { Test } from "@common/types/index";
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2307 ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If anyone knows a solution, please let me know.
If you find any information missing, please feel free to point it out.

### The same error is output even when referencing with a relative path.

#### src/index.ts

```
import { Test } from "../../../common/types/index";
```

#### error

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:7:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../common/types/index' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 import { Test } from "../../../common/types/index";
                      　~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2307 ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

### Communication is possible from Frontend

Frontend is implemented using React (Typescript).

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "extends": ["./tsconfig.paths.json"],
}
```

#### tsconfig.paths.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@common/*": [
        "../../common/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```